# Reduce loading time of webpage with bulk of images

Tags: html, image

Currently I am working on a project in which I have to use 10000 images on a single webpage. I have assign (width="10" height="10") size to each image. But its loading time is too much due to page size.

```html
<div class="item" style="float:left"><div style="margin:0px 0px 0px;width:10px;height:10px"><div style="position:relative;left:0px;top:0px;width:10px;height:10px;"><a href="images/a124032643034b904d21bb1cce2f170a.jpg" target="_blank"><img border=0 width=10 height=10 src="images/a124032643034b904d21bb1cce2f170a.jpg" style="position:relative;left:0px;top:0px" /></a></div></div></div>
```

Please any one help me what should I can do with this code to reduce my loading time and pages.
Here is the url of my webpage
http://alijavedsheikh.com/ubaid/

Comment: setting the width and height of the image in html doens't resize the original image. You will have to resize it before placing it on the webpage. You could also so use some caching.

Answer (score 0):

You could preload the images in javascript using:

```
var x = new Image();
x.src = "someurl";
```

This us similar to saving the images in a string.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `lazyload` plugin, if u have 10000 images, 10000 request passed to the web page and waiting for response. 
Using Lazy Load on long web pages will make the page load faster. In some cases it can also help to reduce server load. 
[This article will help you](https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)